# Recursive struct without pointers? (Huffman)

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

I defined a binary tree this way:

```
struct btree {
    int x;
    btree* left_child = nullptr;
    btree* right_child = nullptr;
};
```

Then I have a vector of floats (`prob_distr`) and I turn each float into a leaf and I put all the leafs into a priority queue (with a custom sort function but it doesn't matter here).

```
auto comp = [] (btree &a, btree &b) -> bool { return a.x > b.x; };
priority_queue<btree, vector<btree>, decltype(comp)> q(comp);

for(auto t: prob_distr)
{
    btree leaf;
    leaf.x = t;
    q.push(leaf);
}
```

For the Huffman algorithm, I then loop on the priority queue until it only has 1 element left: I take the 2 nodes at the top out of the queue, I create a new node with these two nodes as children and I put these new node into the queue.

```
while(q.size() >= 2)
{
    btree left = q.top(); q.pop();
    btree right = q.top(); q.pop();

    btree root;
    root.x = left.x + right.x;
    root.left_child = &left;
    root.right_child = &right;

    q.push(root);
}
```

The problem is that I have pointers to the `left` and `right` binary trees, and these trees are deleted when going out of the while loop. Then I have pointers pointing Nothing. Is there any way to solve this, for example by having a struct which stores the children trees and not just pointers, or by storing the nodes somewhere else without it gets too complicated?

Comment: Yes rhere is a way ro solve this. No you cannot have a recursive struct without pointers. You need to deal with pointers correctly, it's a hard requirement, there's no way around this.

Comment: Assigning `root.left_child = &left` when `left` is a local variable is wrong. You should do something like `btree* left = new btree(q.top())`. Then, you can assign `root.left_child = left`. Same goes for `right`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use pointers here, because the size of the structure has to be known at the compile time. If you would have `struct` itself as a member variable the memory requirement would recursively go to infinity.

You need to dynamically allocate the memory with `new`. The memory allocated with `new` is allocated until you explicitly release it by using `delete`. Just write

```
root.left_child = new btree(left);
root.right_child = new btree(right);
```

As already said, you also need to use `delete` to free the memory of the children. Be careful not to make copies of children which do not get deleted, and not to delete children which are still in use somewhere else. Consider using smart pointers.

Comment: Maybe also say why he needs to allocate dynamically ?

Comment: This answer would benefit from smart pointers. You _don't_ need to use `delete`. This would also eliminate the named risks.

Comment: @MSalters, I added small comment about smart pointers and  I agree he should probably use them. I just left them out originally because I think that a bigger design problem is that the node structure should be inside a separate class, which I felt is outside the scope of the question.